# separating dataset into 2 groups (group 1: ID starting with u and group 2: ID starting with s)

Tags: python

```
    ID     A1     A2  Exam
```

0   u123456  10.00   0.00    21
1   s123457   6.80   9.40    30
2   u123458  13.35  20.00    25
3   u123459   0.00  10.15    24
4   u123460   4.50   8.09    21
5   u123461   5.50  13.30    14
6   u123462  20.00  12.75    16
7   s123463  20.00  17.50    22
8   u123464  11.75  17.30    31
9   s123465   0.00  12.65    15

The above is sample of my dataset, I'm confused how can I make two dataset based on id which starts with 'u' and 's' respectively.  I am new in coding and sorry for asking silly thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the DataFrame using a function that takes the first letter into account.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['s123457', 6.80, 9.40, 30], 
        ['u123458', 13.35, 20.00, 25], 
        ['u123459', 0.00, 10.15, 24], 
        ['u123460', 4.50, 8.09, 21], 
        ['u123461', 5.50, 13.30, 14], 
        ['u123462', 20.00, 12.75, 16], 
        ['s123463', 20.00, 17.50, 22], 
        ['u123464', 11.75, 17.30, 31], 
        ['s123465', 0.00, 12.65, 15] 
    ], 
    columns=['ID', 'A1', 'A2', 'Exam']
)
# Group by the first letter of the ID column.
grouped = df.groupby(lambda index: df['ID'].loc[index][0])
# Output key and associated group, with the index of the group being reset.
for key, group in grouped:
    print(key)
    print(group.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it helps me a lot. I managed to group them according to ID , how can I make two dataframes now ?

Comment: @MahbubAbdullah The groups are already their own DataFrames. You only have to iterate over the generator to query all DataFrames or you can use [`get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html) to get a DataFrame based on the group name.

Comment: still confused, i'm very new in coding. 
I need to get two separate dataframes

Comment: I got it , thanks a lot mate